# Laravel : InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Data missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

When I run the system, there is exist error like this :

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Data missing

    in Carbon.php line 425
    at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '10-12-2016') in Model.php line 2990
    at Model->asDateTime('10-12-2016') in Model.php line 2944
    at Model->fromDateTime('10-12-2016') in Model.php line 2872
    at Model->setAttribute('tglkop', '10-12-2016') in Model.php line 442
```

And my model is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class P3 extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'p3_s';

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'tglkop', 'tglp3'];

    public $fillable = [
        'id_pagu',
        'id_p3',
        'kdbulan',
        'thang',
        'nokop',
        'tglkop',
        'tglp3'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id_pagu' => 'string',
        'id_p3' => 'string',          
        'kdbulan' => 'string',
        'thang' => 'string',
        'nokop' => 'string'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'id_pagu' => 'required',
        'id_p3' => 'required',
        'kdbulan' => 'required',
        'thang' => 'required',
        'nokop' => 'required',
        'tglkop' => 'required',
        'tglp3' => 'required',
    ];


}
```

My table is like this :

```
id, int(10)
id_pagu, varchar(18)
id_p3, varchar(18)
kdbulan, varchar(2)
thang, varchar(4)
nokop, varchar(10)
tglkop, date
tglp3, date
created_at, timestamp
updated_at, timestamp
deleted_at, timestamp
```

I read some tutorial in stackoverflow and laravel docs, but I'm still confused to implement it

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `'tglkop', 'tglp3'` from your `$casts` array, and add this to `'$dates'` array. These properties will be automatically converted to `Carbon` instances

**UPDATE**

I guess that your db columns `tglkop` and `tglp3` have `DATE` type instead of `DATETIME`.

This error

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '10-12-2016') in blah blah blah
```

says that `Carbon` expects date with format `Y-m-d H:i:s` but you gives date in format `d-m-Y` (`10-12-2016`)

**Solution 1**:
change type of these columns to `DATETIME`

**Solution 2**:
add that in your model

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d'; // this is expected format for `MySQL` `DATE` type field
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think you tries to create row in database. What data are you trying to pass into? I think `tglkop` and `tglp3` fields in your input have wrong format.

Comment: I had update my question according to you answers. But, it's the same. It's not working. Look my update question

Comment: There exist error like this : `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '09-12-2016' for column 'tglkop' at row 1...`

Comment: I update my question. Look it. I add my table(field and data type) too. There exist field with data type date and field with data type timestamp

Comment: So, when I add this : `protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y';`,there exist error like this : `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '09-12-2016' for column 'tglkop' at row 1...`

Comment: I had repair the format date like this :`protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';`. And now can insert in database. But, the field created_at and updated_at, the contain like this : `2016-12-07 00:00:00`. The time contain `00:00:00`

Comment: cause of format in `$dateFormat` property time is ignored

Comment: means for my problem using `solution 1` or there is another solution again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130037/discussion-between-piotr-and-samuel-toh).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when deploying a Laravel application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.

The solution was to change the date column from timestamp(1) to DATETIME on the MySQL database.

Hope this helps!